# regular expression to extract tables after the FROM clause in a Select statement

Tags: regex

I have a file in unix which have a list of select statements of the form.

```
Select Colmn, From Table, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table2, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table3,Table4 Where ....
```

and so on.

Is there a regular expression which can extract all the table names from the file?

For cases of

```
Select Colmn, From Table3,Table4 Where ....
```

I need both Table3 and Table4. I believe a simple regex wont do? I probably would have to write a program to do this? And how about this case,

```
Select Colmn,
  From Table3 ,
  Table4 
   Where ....
```

Here both tables are on multiple lines.

Comment: There certainly is.  You going to load the list into a db and extract there, or trying to do this from the command line/in a script?

Comment: command line in script. cat input.txt | perl -ne '$\ = $/; print for /\sfrom\s+(\w+)/ig'. This command works perfectly however, if there are more than one table after "," and new line it ignores them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are missing a `,` in your attempt

```
perl -ne '$\ = $/; print for /\sfrom\s+([\w,]+)/ig' input.txt
```

---

```
$ cat input.txt
Select Colmn, From Table, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table2, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table3,Table4 Where ....

$ perl -ne '$\ = $/; print for /\sfrom\s+([\w,]+)/ig' input.txt
Table,
Table2,
Table3,Table4
```

Adding an example with `sed` to get Tables on multiple lines:

```
$ cat input.txt
Select Colmn, From Table, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table2, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table3,
Table4
Where ....
$
$ sed -e 's/.*From //' -e 's/Where.*$//' -e '/^$/d' input.txt
Table,
Table2,
Table3,
Table4
```

Comment: thank you so much. However for my learning, let say if select is on multiple lines so the last select is like this.Select Colmn, From Table3,\nTable4\n Where .... How will i match Table3 and Table4 now?

Comment: lol. Thanks again. However, now the issue is that we are assuming Table names to be Table[0-9], which was just an example. Basically we need everything after "from" and before "where" basically.

Comment: Thank you again so much. However it doesnt work on this example i edited in your original post. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `perl` one-liner to match your patterns.

```
perl -ne '$/=undef; print $_ . "\n" for /(?<=from)\s*(\S*\s*\S*)\s*(?=where)/ig' file
```

```
$ cat file
Select Colmn, From Table, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table2, Where ....
Select Colmn, From Table3,Table4 Where ....
Select Colmn,
  From Table5,
  Table6
   Where ....
```

```
$ perl -ne '$/=undef; print $_ . "\n" for /(?<=from)\s*(\S*\s*\S*)\s*(?=where)/ig' file
Table,
Table2,
Table3,Table4
Table5,
  Table6
```

This should match most of your statements, unless you have a select statements that has tables on spread across more than two lines. In that case, feel free to play around with the regex to best suit your needs.